# Xorg does not work after uninstallation of Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I updated my 14.05 with Vivid 15.04 HWE stack yesterday and now it does not work. I tried thing that worked for me in the past and that was uninstalling the nvidia driver and installing it again. Then it magically worked once again (I suspect it was DKMS module).

Now I cannot load Xorg. It just does not load and the system loading is stoppend on this step.
I tried reinstalling as I mentiond and also installing the newest drivers from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa and these are showing the same result. With removal of xorg.conf.
I also tried to purge nvidia drivers and revert to nouveau, but this does not work so. Surprisingly if I unmount my Nvidia driver from PCI slot and plug HDMI for Intel GPU the system works.

The best possible solution would be how to revert back to nouveau driver.
Thanks in forward.

Comment: How did you `purge` the drivers ? To remove them completely run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`, perhaps some part was left over if you used something like `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-352`???

Comment: I did purge them with sudo apt-get purge nvidia* and then installed back nvidia-common. Checked /etc/modules for nouveau driver line, everything looks ok to me, but it does not work.

Comment: `nvidia-common` is depreciated.. New version is `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`

Comment: It installed the driver but now I end up being in terminal. But at the first time of booting after installation I ended up in working Xorg.

Xserver log file has this interesting line: drmSetMaster failed: Invalid argument

Comment: So it worked once but now just a cli ? Try to roll it back, like this `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-352 && reboot` to make sure it is gone, then `sudo apt-get install nvidia 340`

Comment: "drmSetMaster failed: Invalid argument" Try running `nvidia-xconfig` after installing the driver.

Comment: I found about a pretty odd pattern. When I go into recovery mode, the kernel and some system parts load and then I choose "resume - in normal boot process" the Xorg works as charm. I guess this is not the optimal way how to make it work.

Comment: It worked! Thank you man, you are my hero! :)
I wish u merry christmas!

Comment: No worries, if I make an answer please accept with the check mark, to say thanks and help others find the correct solution. merry Christmas!

Comment: Sure. I will do so.

Comment: If you like new hardware drivers I added the very latest from Nvidia to the answer.

Comment: I will rather stay with this working version. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvidia-common` is depreciated in 15.04, you can use `nvidia-352`

First make sure that `nvidia-common` is completely removed

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && reboot
```

Now install the newer driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Now run

```
nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot
```

Now your desktop should load.

If you like the most up to date drivers for hardware, you can use this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot
```